# Class Project Pass Service Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

This one is stumping me, but I'm sure there's a way to do it I'm missing. 
I have a C# class project that handles some logic. I have an Interface that connects to a "ServiceContext", which then consumes a WCFService.

One of the calls inside the "ServiceContext" looks like

```
GetData("username","password","dbname")
```

, all as Strings.

In my MVC web app, I would like to to be able to change the value of "dbname" to be different when I **deploy**, just like the transformation of my other database connections (via Web.Config).

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ServiceContext" value="dbname2" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? It's more trying to pass a variable to the Class Library, rather than a full connection string, but I can't seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AppSettings:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="databaseName" value="dbname2" />
</appSettings>
```

Then in your code:

```
string databaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseName"];
someClient.GetData("username", "password", databaseName);
```

Note this will use the configuration of the executing application, not that of the library.

Comment: This was my next option, but the only challenge is that I have to add dbName to every function in that Service and pass it like a variable. Perhaps I'm missing how to pass this variable when I instantiate the interface? (Just when I think I understand IoC :-/)